# Can we make the [table] tag language specific?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

I've seen that the [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) tag has a *do not use* in its information.

In the [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) language the `table` function is fairly useful and delivers a matrix/array data-object. Is there a mechanism to support a language-specific [r-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-table) or [r:table] tag?

Comment: You can always make a new tag r-table, just like there's dozens of tags under android-XXX.  There's no automated way of doing that categorizing.

Comment: From the [table tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/table/info): R uses the [tag:data.table] tag.

Comment: Just to clarify, is there any dash versus colon convention in tags. In [R] the colon seems more natural since `::` is the `package::function` mechanism and colon is used in some other argument and formula  interpretations.

Comment: @animuson: that is entirely different. `data.table` is a package with the same named function as its constructor. It is NOT the same at `table`.

Comment: @BondedDust Colons are not allowed in tag names.

Comment: If either of you want to construct an answer that combines those two concepts I accept. But I'm still interested in what the retag-request tag implies. Is the implication that I should go into all of the 400 co-tagged {r{ and {table] entries?

Comment: As no questions have the  both the [r] and [table] tag, do you consider this to be completed? The r-table tag was not created so I assume only the retagging was done?

Comment: I means someone or its machine avatar has removed the table tags that previously existed. They did not, however, replace them with [r-table] tags.

Comment: @animuson: you're requoting a total misunderstanding by the wiki editor, as @42- noted. In R we might mean either: a) `table` as in statistical `tabulate/tabulation` (not necessarily using `base::tabulate`, could equally be, `summarize/ aggregate/ xtabs/ prop.table/ margin.table` etc. or b) `data.table` package (or c) some other generic language-agnostic sense, such as Shiny/Jupyter/HTML/JSON et al. tables). I will write an answer here. For a) we probably want [tag:tabulate], for b) [tag:data.table], for c) arguably should use a generic tag (e.g. html-table) or no tag, since it will be misused

Comment: @smci so, neither table nor *.table should be tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) tag was deleted:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/table/

So this question no longer arises.

(And as to the original question, the concept of ***'statistical table'*** (as a 2D matrix/array object with a well-defined set of ***numerical*** methods, e.g. pivot, aggregate, etc., as opposed to SQL or web or formatting tables) is **not** specific to R, it occurs in Python [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29), [Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark), and other languages/tools.)

Comment: Yes I see that all tags== `[table]` have been expunged. The use in R is a bit different than a statistical "table". I was thinking of it more as a verb to create a possibly multiway  tabulation, i.e. a count within an array structure. I suppose a [tabulate] tag can substitute. But what happened was that the ambiguity-driven decision to burminate the tag  resulted in a loss of useful tagging. I think that rather than simply deleting the tag, that it should have been migrated. At the moment  that are exactly 8 [tabulate[ tags associated with [r]. Should be many more.

Comment: @IRFTM: I've used both R and pandas for 10 years, and I don't think your claim is correct, so can you please justify with a succinct example why an R table is yet another different type of object to (say) a Python pandas table? And no we can't create/hijack an ambiguous tag [tabulate] because presumably that term/verb exists in like 10-100 other languages/packages and means something different in each. So the short and long answer is there should not be a tag [r-table]

Comment: @IRTFM: I invite you to come discuss this in the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), some other people can contribute

Comment: (Didn't see the invitation until this morning) In R `table` is a verb that created an array (with more than 2 dimensions) or matrix-like object with class "table". .)  I do think that [tabulate] could be used and my whinging was that the wholesale removal of the [table] tag in association with an [r] tag might better have been a more careful substitution with [tabulate].

Comment: Perhaps a pandas tables is similar, because as I understand it, pandas was modeled after R data structures, but I don't think an R table object is always like an SQL table since R-tables are generally contingency tables. (If pandas tables are always 2D then they are not isomorphic to R tables

Comment: @IRTFM: nobody was ever talking about SQL tables. *'The use in R is a bit different than a statistical "table".'* No it's not, it's precisely that, enriched with lots of methods. Whether in R or Python pandas. Please read the Python pandas doc and compare to R before telling us it isn't...

Comment: I have no desire to reserve this as an R tag. I would be happy to have a tag that was more polyglot as long as it included the multiway aggregation or counting aspects of the `table`, `aggregate`, and `tapply` verbs in R as well as any equivalents in any other language. I guess [tabulate] or [aggregate] would suffice. I'll mark as accepted.